# Vuejs - Chartjs - turning a doughnut chart to a gauge - rotation

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, chart.js, vue-component, vue-chartjs

I am new to vue.js and your help and advise would be much appreciated.

I am using Chartjs and i would like to rotate my pie chart so it looks like a gauge. I am unsure where i am going wrong with my javascript and i am getting no errors in the console - could one kindly advise me

i am unsure if i have not placed "options" in the right place

chartjs.html

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="chart_header">chartjs guage</div>
  <vue-chartsguagejs></vue-chartsguagejs>
</div>
```

chartsjsgauge.js

```
import { Doughnut } from 'vue-chartjs'

export default {
  extends: Doughnut,
  mounted () {
    this.renderChart({
      labels: ["Log Level", "Debug", "Info", "Warn", "Error", "Fatal"],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'GitHub Commits',
        backgroundColor: ['rgb(255, 255, 255)', 'rgb(232,226,202)', 'rgb(226,210,172)', 'rgb(223,189,139)', 'rgb(223,162,103)','rgb(226,126,64)'],
        borderWidth: 0,
        hoverBorderWidth: 0,
        data: [50, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
      }],
      options: {
        cutoutPercentage: 0,
        rotation: -3.1415926535898,
        circumference: 3.1415926535898,
      }
    }, {responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false})
  }
}
```

this is currently my dougnut chart which i am trying to rotate as a gauage
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found that restructuring my code in this format made a huge difference:

```
import { Doughnut } from 'vue-chartjs'

export default {
  extends: Doughnut,
  data () {
    return {
      datacollection: {
        labels: ["Log Level", "Debug", "Info", "Warn", "Error", "Fatal"],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'GitHub Commits',
            backgroundColor: ['rgb(226,126,64)', 'rgb(232,226,202)', 'rgb(226,210,172)', 'rgb(223,189,139)', 'rgb(223,162,103)','rgb(226,126,64)'],
            borderWidth: 0,
            hoverBorderWidth: 0,
            data: [10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        rotation: -1.0 * Math.PI,
        circumference: Math.PI,
      }

    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.renderChart(this.datacollection, this.options, {responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false})
  }
}
```

[image]